# Отключить открытие десктопных приложений через Chrome

Tags: браузер

Я перерыл много сайтов, а также потратил значительное время на то, чтобы найти ответ, но всё безуспешно.Вопрос в том, как отключить сообщения по типу "Сайт *** собирается открыть это приложение."? Единственное что я вычитал, это создать в реестре ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox со значением 1 для того, чтобы появилась возможность ставить галочку в поле "Запомнить мой выбор", но это мне не помогает, так как это поле не появляется. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть ответ?